# Asp.net treview image padding

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a treeview that I am creating dynamically from xml (via a web service) and I have it populating and formatting mostly the way I want.  However, the one thing that I'm still having some difficulty with is being able to manipulate some of the items within each element of the treeview.  Sepcifically, each of the image that I'm using to represent the various node levels.  From the source it looks like it's just an image tag in an a tag, which in turn is within at td. However none of these have classes associated with them.  Is there a standard way of manipulating spacing or formatting within each node of a treeview?  Searching hasn't been very successful but maybe I'm not looking for the right thing...

Answer (score 2):

Since you've noticed the hideous markup that some of the ASP.NET server controls produce, check out the [CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/Default.aspx). Rather than writing out nested tables, the control adapters will render markup that is much easier to work with.

Here is a sample output from a [TreeView control](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/treeview.aspx). The `li` elements have classes which you can use when styling their child elements.